# Google analytics 2 not working in Android

Tags: android, google-analytics

I have Android project /supports all versions from api8/. Admob and Analytics work fine until I decided to migrate analytics to version 2/beta5/ and admob to 6.4.1.
Now I see in LogCat that my Analytics code is not sending to analytics site. At first looked all solutions posted in stackoverflow, but problems remains.

Finally created new project. Everything in project is same as original - target api, min api, admob sdk version, analytics sdk version. Same code for banners and analytics. Test project works fine.

Tried clear and rebuild lot of times - nothing. Something in project is different.
Will try to copy whole code in this project, but this is not good solution, because if this happens again - whole procedure have to be repeated.

Please help!

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13446505/google-analytics-v2-not-recording-stats-from-android-app/13450529#13450529

Comment: This is not the same case. I've already done this steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem id because of intervals in strings sendView and sendEvent. I didn't see recommendation in help to avoid spaces!